# When can we extend a function on a $\lambda$-system to a probability measure?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a nonempty set and let $\mathcal{L}$ a $\lambda$-system on $\Omega$. That is,

(i) $\Omega \in \mathcal{L}$,
(ii) if $A, B \in \mathcal{L}$ and $A \subseteq B$, then $B \setminus A \in \mathcal{L}$, and
(iii) if $\{A_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty \subseteq \mathcal{L}$ and $A_n \subseteq A_{n + 1}$, then $\bigcup_n A_n \in \mathcal{L}$.

Let $P_0: \mathcal{L} \to [0,1]$ satisfy

(a) $P_0(\Omega) = 1$,
(b) if $A, B \in \mathcal{L}$ and $A \subseteq B$, then $P_0(B \setminus A) = P_0(B) - P_0(A)$, and
(c) if $\{A_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty \subseteq \mathcal{L}$ and $A_n \subseteq A_{n + 1}$, then $P_0(\bigcup_n A_n) = \lim_n P_0(A_n)$.

Is it necessarily the case that there exists a probability measure $P$ on $(\Omega, \sigma(\mathcal{L}))$ such that $P|_\mathcal{L} = P_0$?

I have not seen anything like this before and my initial search did not turn up anything. Granted, it is a little hard to search for, since most of the search results are about the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem. The same question [was asked 5 years ago on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2528391/11867), but it received no comments or answers. I started a bounty on it, but if no one answered it 5 years ago, I doubt it will gain traction. Hence, I thought it appropriate to post here. Has anyone seen anything like this or know of any references that discuss this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no, for quite a trivial reason: $\mathcal{L}$ may have not enough pairs $A\subset B$, and not enough monotone increasing sequences $(A_n)_n$, to make $(a)$ and $(b)$ meaningful. For instance, take $\Omega:=\{1,2,\dots,10\}$ and $\mathcal{L}:=\{A\subset \Omega: |A|= 5\}\cup\{\Omega\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$. It is quite obviously a $\lambda$-system, and generates the whole power set algebra $2^\Omega$.

Define $P_0(\Omega):=1$, and choose arbitrarily a value   $P_0(A)\in[0,1]$,  for those $\frac12 {10 \choose 5}>100$ sets $A\in \mathcal L\setminus\{\Omega\}$ such that $1\in A$, and for the remaining ones, put $P_0(A):=1-P_0(A^c)$. Of course this has little chance to be the restriction of a measure on $2^\Omega$, which is determined by just the values on the $10$ points.

Comment: We cannot assign quite an arbitrary value to $P_0(A)$ for $A$ with $1\in A$. This value has to be $<4/9$ -- see my answer for details.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, I guess what Pietro means is that any assignment of $P_0(A)$, allowing this quantity to depend on $A$, satisfy the conditions (a) - (c) in the OP. Those coming from measures form a 9-dimensional submanifold in the ${10 \choose 5}$-dimensional hypercube, which cannot be the whole hypercube.

Comment: @Kostya_I : First, a minor point: even if we allow different values of $P_0(A)$ for $A$ with $1\in A$, the dimension will be $\frac12\,\binom{10}5$, rather than $\binom{10}5$. But the main point here is that, even then, we cannot assign values of $P_0(A)$ for $A$ with $1\in A$ **arbitrarily**, if we want to rule out a measure.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes, of course there are few $P_0$ that are actually restrictions of true measures on $2^\Omega$, but for just the sake of the existence of a counterexample it is sufficient to know that these are a proper subset, indeed of dimension $9$ vs dimension $\frac12{10\choose5}$ (this is what I meant by “little chance”).

Comment: To rule out the restriction of a true measure, we can e.g. define $P_0(A)=1$ and $P_0(A^c)=0$, for all $A\in\mathcal L$ containing $1$, but the set $B:=\{1,7,8,9,10\}$ to which we assign $P_0(B)=0$ and $P_0(B^c)=1$ (so, by the corresponding linear system, the values of $P_0$ on $\mathcal {L}\setminus \{B,B^c\}$ are compatible only with the measure concentrated at $\{1\}$, which is however not admissible on $B$ because $P_0(B)=0$)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\L{\mathcal L}\newcommand\Om{\Omega}$This is to complement the nice idea by [Pietro Majer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/437696/36721) by considering "choose arbitrarily a value $P_0(A)\in[0,1]$" and "this has little chance" in detail.

Let us refer to a subset $A$ of the set $\Om:=[10]:=\{1,\dots,10\}$ of cardinality $5$ as a $5$-set. Say that a $5$-set $A$ is good if $1\in A$, and say that a $5$-set $A$ is bad if $1\notin A$.

We assign the same value $p:=P_0(A)$ to all good $5$-sets and the same value $1-p$ to all bad $5$-sets.

Suppose that there is a probability measure $P$ on $2^\Om$ whose restriction to $\L:=\{\emptyset,\Om\}\cup\{A\subset\Om\colon|A|=5\}$ is $P_0$. Let $p_j:=P(\{j\})$ for $j\in\Om$.

Then $p_1+p_2+p_4+p_5+p_6=p=p_1+p_3+p_4+p_5+p_6$, so that $p_2=p_3$. Similarly, $p_2=\cdots=p_{10}$, so that $$p_2=\cdots=p_{10}=\frac{1-p_1}9.\tag{1}\label{1} $$

So,
$$p=p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4+p_5=p_1+4\dfrac{1-p_1}9=\dfrac{5p_1}9+\frac49\ge\frac49. \tag{2}\label{2} $$
Choosing now any $p\in[0,\frac49)$, we get a contradiction. $\quad\Box$

(This consideration also shows that, if we choose any $p\in[\frac49,1]$, then there will exist a probability measure $P$ on $2^\Om$ whose restriction to $\L$ is $P_0$. Indeed, in view of \eqref{2}, this probability measure $P$ is determined by the conditions $p_1=(p-\frac49)/\frac59$ and \eqref{1}.)

Comment: Nice remark, thank you -And if we don’t bother all the good ones  to have the same value $p$ (how it sadly happens in real life),  we may e.g. take $P_0$ to coincide with a true probability  $P$ on all $A\in\mathcal L$, but on a pair $B, B^c$ (so any extension $\tilde P_0$ of it on $2^\Omega$ can’t be a measure, because the difference $P-\tilde P_0$ would be a signed measure vanishing on any set, in particular on points,  but with non-zero values on $B$ and $B^c$)

Comment: @PietroMajer : I like your sense of humor ... "how it sadly happens in real life".